# Visual Studio with qt fails to compile gui class

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I have recently found this tool that allows to use qt within visual studio so I wanted to give it a try. 
Click [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TheQtCompany.QtVisualStudioTools-19123) to see which tool I used.

So I just installed that tool and of course install qt (version 5.11.0), then in Visual Studio a new menu appears referring to qt in which I have to set up the path to include qt. Before that, in the installation of qt I must specify also to install the integration with visual studio 2017 (its not default) and this way I can set up the path.

[Here is the options of qt in visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ww9He.png)

Now is when the problems begin, I created a qt project and tried to compile, it works fine with no problem at all. But then I tried to add a GUI class with the assistant and compile again, in this case some errors appear related with unresolved external symbols.

[Visual Studio errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faFuN.png)

There is also a warning in the gui class with Q_OBJECT, after some research I found that this might be the problem but since its my first time with qt I have no idea.

This is the code of the GUI class I created.

```
#pragma once

#include <QtWidgets/qwidget.h>
#include <GeneratedFiles/ui_WindowTFG.h>

class WindowTFG : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    WindowTFG(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    ~WindowTFG();

private:
    Ui::WindowTFG ui;
};
```

This is my version of visual studio and qt.
Visual Studio 2017 15.7.1 - Qt 5.11.0

If anybody can point me out to the right direction I would be grateful.

Comment: Do you have a .lib file anywhere that you need to add in Linker > Input in the project properties?

Comment: @Paul I don't have any .lib file since visual studio already handle the conection with qt, you just need to include the path of qt directory in visual studio options as I showed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, since nobody seems to know where the problem is im gonna update the situation just in case it could be useful for somebody.

I could not compile my project but I found a "way" for using qt in visual studio, in the moment that you create a qt project in visual studio I selected "qt console application", well, instead of that option I tried "qt GUI application" which already creates a project with a GUI class. This time I could compile my project and use it as usual, the difference with the class which I could not compile is a file with extension ".qrc" (besides .h, .cpp and .ui files) so my guess is that because of that missing file my previous project was not working properly.

Hope this could be useful for somebody with similar problems.

I will leave this question unresolved for a time in case another user can explain this.